# How to start a user journey map for a new product and how does it translate to a product backlog?

Tags: user-research, personas, user-journey, product-management

I'm working on a new product that's a talent marketplace for the events and entertainment space. The client has a rough idea (like 20%) of what the user journey would be like.

I'm curious how should i go about setting up the foundations for a user journey map. Right now i've identified 3 personas that would use the product for different reasons and i'm guessing there will be 3 user journeys.

Should i brainstorm with the client to build this journey? If so what would be a suitable brainstorming method? Also how could i validate this journey with real users?

Lastly, as the user journey gets more detailed, how this would connect to the product roadmap or product backlog?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link on the customer journey: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/analyze-customer-journey-map/

1. yes, you should create separate "routes" for all the different customer
2. once main tipping points identified, fell free to do a survey
3. once pain-points (issues) analyzed and collected, based on that you will create backlogs and product road-map (by focusing on the most important / severe problems).

Comment: thank you for your answer. could you give a bit more details in how the survey should be planned out to answer the tipping points? and how will the results of the survey be used? could you give some examples to help me understand better?

Comment: try to go over the same journey a regular your user would have: 1) sees the ad (what are his first impressions) 2) goes to a web (landing page) to get information - will (s)he find what (s)he might be looking for 3) finds a store (or web shop) - how hard to find store, how hard to get the desired item into the basket (e-shop) and order it, how good your parcell service provider is (flexible time delivery)...

Comment: 4) user gets package - again: first impression, how hard to open, is there too much waste (packaging) - you client might be interested in the enviro aspect as much as to the extravaganza factor; 5) is there a battery supplied with, how hard is it to get running the first time; 6) UI/UX - how hard it is to use; 7) what value it adds... You can use shadowing an user, focus groups and surveys over them... You might get a lot of good inputs from them.